# Time taken by power supply to reach output voltage

Tags: power-supply, timing, scpi

My question is regarding programmable power supplies. If I send a SCPI command to the power supply using USB/RS-232 or some other serial communication, how do i know the time taken by the power supply to reach the programmed voltage or time taken by the power supply to interpret the command.

Is this parameter usually mentioned in the data-sheet of the power supply? 
I am planning on renting a power supply which can turn off and turn on remotely within 4 msec, so i want to be sure that the power supply which i rent has that feature before i put my money down on it.

The power supplies I'm looking at are:

1. Sorensen XG60-28 DC Power Supply, 0-60V, 0-28A,1700W
2. Keithley Series 2260B 360W
3. Tektronix PWS4305

Update: Found an example of what I'm looking for:
[RIGOL DP800A Series Programmable Linear
DC Power Supply[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvhCQ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvhCQ.jpg)

I need some similar timing parameter which can process the command in less than 1 mSec

Comment: A SCPI command of 10 characters send via RS-232 with 19200 baud will need at least 5.7 msec for transmission. At 9600 baud 11.5 msec. Look for baud rate and command length to calculate yourself.

Comment: The baud rate required would be 38400 bps or higher. But my question is the following - after the entire command is sent from pc to power supply(2.25 mSec at 38400 bps) how much time will the power supply need to process the command and change its voltage?

Answer (score 1):

this catalog has more info for the Keithley stuff, for the 2260 they do not have actual response times for commands, but mostly how long it takes the unit to change or recover from different load situations. Rise or fall, etc. Seems under 50ms is typical.

The 2600 series seems to be at the speed range you mentioned, you can search for COMMAND PROCESSING TIME in the document and see for yourself they state under 1ms for commands there.

other models have under 10ms.

http://lmnov.ru/upload/eng/Keithley_2014_eng.pdf